# Can a function be both upper and lower quasi-continuous?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can you give me a non-trivial example? Below is the definition I am using:

A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be upper (lower) quasi-continuous at $x \in X$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ and for each neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there is a non-empty  open set $G \subset U$ such that $f(y)< f(x) + \epsilon$ ($f(y)> f(x) - \epsilon$), for each $y \in G$.

Comment: Any continuous function?

Comment: Is $$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }x<1 \\
2, & \text{if }x=1 \\
3, & \text{if }x > 1

\end{cases}
$$

quasi-continuous? Why?

Comment: Try applying the definition with $x=1$ and $\epsilon=1/2$ and see what happens. Drawing a picture helps.

Comment: Are you sure that the definition does not require $x\in G$? The answer depends on that.

Comment: $x$ need not be in $G$

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen It works still doesn't it?

Comment: Wait, wait … Your question title said semicontinuous, yet the text is about quasi(semi)continuity. I got thrown by this, not being familiar with [quasicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-continuous_function), so I figured you just used the wrong word. (And I did not read your definition carefully, being familiar with semicontinuity after all.) Disregard everything I said before. I'll edit the question title now.

Comment: Yes, your function is quasi-continuous at $1$. Just let $G=U\cap(1,2)$ or $G=U\cap(0,1)$ depending on which inequality you wish to have.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Is quasi-continuity not the same as semi-continuity not the same? The function I defined is not quasi-continuous, however I wanted to know if it is upper/lower/ both?

Comment: Not at all! [Semicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicontinuity) needs $x\in G$ (and then there is no need for $U$ in the definition). But semicontinuity *implies* quasi-contiinuity.

Answer (score 2):

For a slightly non-trivial example, consider 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)&x\ne0,\\a&x=0.\end{cases}$$
I think you will find that this function is quasi-continuous (i.e. upper and lower) if $\lvert a\rvert\le1$, more generally upper quasi-continuous iff $a\ge -1$ and lower quasi-continuous iff $a\le1$.